# Serilog C# how to prevent logging big data e.g. image data or large JSON object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, serilog

Serilog using C# how to prevent logging big data e.g. image data or large JSON object

How to configure the Log api of serilog to have logging-data check to log the input till an extent.

> Example:

```
serilogLoggerInstance.Information("input"); -- input should have check to log if its below a define size. e.g. image data, large JSON object
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to check the string input's length before passing it to the Information function? If it exceeds the length specified then don't log it?

Comment: @XenoXetric I want to configure this in serilog configuration somewhere instead of manually checking input everywhere. it will be convenient. as currently our system has 80GB logs per day which has unnecessary byte arrays and big JSON data

Comment: I'm not really sure if this is a solution, but you could look at a [log "enricher"](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment).

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that logging large amount of data could be useful in some cases, but it should probably only be logged on specific request when investigating some bug. So my advice would be to establish some policy regarding what should be logged, to what level and how frequently. Keep in mind that you can log to multiple levels:

```
serilogLoggerInstance.Information("Received image of size: {image.Size}");
serilogLoggerInstance.Verbose("Received image Data: {image.Data}");
```

A problem with enforcing some limit is what the limit should be. To small and you will lose important logging information. To large and you will not reduce the log size much. Some technical solution might still be valuable to find the sources of poor log messages, but I have no idea how to implement something like that in serilog. You could always create a decorator for the logger, but that would only be feasible if you inject the logger, and are not using some static factory or instance.

Comment: sounds good. but I need the same piece of checking the size inside/ or as an extension of the framework(if I can override) i.e. if the size is above threshold then don't log data. It applied to big plain strings that we can't filter for even image.size or image.data etc. 

we will be able to  filter data.size but it should be controlled from central piece of code which is what I am looking for. if the decorator is injectable might help but our case is Serilog and needs to check with IoC container also.

Comment: @Abdul Nasir Khayam If I as developer logs some large string and it silently throws away my message, I would be quite confused. I would suggest truncating the length instead. That way I at least see some message.